# A-frame position animation passing in data as second argument

Tags: aframe

I am trying to get an animation to move the camera from the current position, to a position passed from the element clicked. The issue seems to be in proper syntax for passing the 'to' position into an animation. Here is what I have.

```
<a-entity id="cam-position" position="0 0 1.2" rotation="-0 0 0">
        <a-camera look-controls wasd-controls>
          <a-entity visible="true" cursor="fuse: true; fuse-timeout: 500"
                position="0 0 -1"
                scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"
                geometry="primitive: sphere"
                material="color: #6AD7FF; shader: standard">
                <a-animation begin="click" 
                  easing="ease-in" 
                  attribute="scale" 
                  dur="2000"
                  fill="backwards" 
                  from="0.01 0.01 0.01" to="0.04 0.04 0.04">
                </a-animation>
                <a-animation begin="fusing" 
                  easing="ease-in" 
                  attribute="scale"
                  fill="forwards" 
                  from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" >
                </a-animation>
          </a-entity> 
        </a-camera>
      <a-animation begin="move" 
                  attribute="position"
                  dur="2000"
                  from="0 0 1.2"
                  >
                </a-animation>
      </a-entity>

document.querySelector('#cam-position').emit('move',{'to': { x: 0, y: 0, z: -88 } });
```

It works fine without the second argument and the 'to' specified in the a-animation. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are emitting `move`, the second argument is the event detail. Animations do have a feature to start an animation on an event trigger, but it doesn't look at the event detail.

You'd need to do a `animation.setAttribute('to', {...})` rather than trying to have an event handle everything since that's not a feature.

```
document.querySelector('a-animation[begin="move"]').setAttribute('to', '0 0 -88');
document.querySelector('#cam-position').emit('move')
```

Comment: The animation is still not taking place. The position attr is changed to '0 0 -88', but the animation is defaulting to the old attribute. Console logging shows it has changed. Does the camera entity need to be updated to reflect the new 'to' position or am I missing something else?

Comment: You could also try this API: https://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/components/animation/

Comment: Same with kframe/animation.